# A way to predict an outcome of a single value but train and input on a much wider range of input data in RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Let's say we have a basketball player log stats (just because it has a lot of stats to pick from).
So there is like Points, Rebounds, Assists, FG%, 3PT% etc. And we can add the opposing team stats (the one that our player haven't played yet).

Is it the correct way to mix the history data and the stats of next opposing team to better predict an outcome?
And the main question: is there a way to predict a single value (Points as the easiest example) but from this wide range of input values? I would love to read something on it (like an article or a code example) but I couldn't find anything related, probably because my terminology is wrong :)

p.s. coding language doesn't matter it could be matlab/python/etc, I'm just trying to understand a concept and should be able to read any language

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  As you say, your terminology is likely wrong.  This indicates that you need to learn the terminology.  Then you need to learn the basic use models -- information which is readily available from many introductions to training NNs.  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge collection of how to articles and tutorials to apply machine learning. `Scikit-learn` is a popular machine learning Python package to do what you are asking, particularly a linear regression model. Take a look at this tutorial [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scikit-learn-tutorial-baseball-1).

To answer your question about "mixing the historical data", the basic answer is yes you can do that, and if you think or know that a feature is highly correlated to the target, then yes I would include it.

For example, if I wanted to predict how many passing yards Tampa Bay will have against the Kansas City in the Super Bowl, I'll want my dataset to be setup so that I have games (each row) the passing yards of team that game (my target variable), and the opponents' passing defense (whatever stats I may include with that) going into that game. So it will take a bit of processing and shifting of values (as remember we have to think in terms of how many passing yards an offense gets, given the opponent's pass defense going **into** the game). We probably also want to include the offenses passing offense stats going into the game too.

So if we have a bunch of historical data/rows that says team A went into a game averaging 300 pass yards per game, and team B (the opposition defense) went into a game allowing 400 yards per game, the offense got 450 passing yards (or whatever it was for the game). You create enough of those rows to train your day, then when you feed in a new row with an unknown outcome, you use those features to predict your target variable.

You can apply this also to RNN. I'd suggest `Keras`. You can also look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) or [here](https://www.lynda.com/Google-TensorFlow-tutorials/Building-Deep-Learning-Applications-Keras-2-0/601801-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3akeras%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2).